# akka-stream and mockito: value thenReturn is not a member of Nothing

Tags: scala, mockito, akka-stream

I am trying to mock a method which returns type:

```
Future[Option[(ContentType, Long, Source[ByteString, NotUsed])]]
```

I mock as:

```
when(service.fetchData(id)).thenReturn(Future.successful(
            Some((ContentTypes.`application/octet-stream`, 1000, Source("Dummy Byte string")))
    )
)
```

Bu it gives me error as:

```
value thenReturn is not a member of Nothing
        when(service.fetchData(id)).thenReturn(Future.successful(
```

I don't see any mismatch between mocked return value and return type.

What is missing here?

Edit: I got it working with:

```
val source = Source.single(ByteString("Some dummy string"))
when(service.fetchData(id)).thenReturn(Future.successful(
            Some((ContentTypes.`application/octet-stream`, 1000, source))
    )
)
```

Comment: How is `service` defined?

Comment: Have you tried the alternative, `doReturn(Future.successful(...)).when(service).fetchData(id)`? (just a quick idea, in case it helps - giving some more details as asked by previous comments would probably lead to a more complete approach)